# Javascript get more than one id at a time

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm just wondering if its possible in javascript to get more than one id at a time, without the use of JQuery.  I'm checking the background color of each cell in a dynamically created table. For instance, I have this code:

```
var black = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
if(document.getElementById("cell1").style.backgroundColor == black &&
   document.getElementById("cell2").style.backgroundColor == black)
{
  alert("Two cells are black!");
}
```

Would it be possible to do something like this:

```
var black = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
if(document.getElementById("cell1","cell2").style.backgroundColor == black)
{
  alert("Two cells are black!");
}
```

I'm trying not to use JQuery at all as I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: No such feature exists.

Comment: No. By the very nature of the function, `getElementById` should only ever return one element. You could easily write your own, though.

Comment: Maybe you can use jQuery, for do that.

Comment: "I'm trying not to use JQuery at all as I'm not too familiar with it." => good decision, wrong reason ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With modern browsers you can do something similar using `querySelectorAll` ([compatibility matrix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)), but you'd still have to loop over the resulting `NodeList`:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#cell1, #cell2");
var count = 0;
for (var index = 0; index < nodes.length; ++index) {
    if (nodes[index].style.backgroundColor == black) {
        ++count;
     }
}
if (nodes.length === count) {
    alert("Both are black");
}
```

Doesn't really buy you anything over, say:

```
var cells = ["cell1", "cell2"];
var count = 0;
for (var index = 0; index < cells.length; ++index) {
    if (document.getElementById(cells[index]).style.backgroundColor == black) {
        ++count;
    }
}
if (cells.length === count) {
    alert("All cells are black");
}
```

So in short: No, there isn't really anything more useful you can do.

Answer (score 1):

No,
without using jQuery or other javascript helper libraries.

querySelector is not supported by IE7 and below which still represents a fairly large proportion of the traffice http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Answer (score 1):

Not natively. You could write your own fairly easily, though:

```
function getElementsById(elements)
{
    var to_return = [ ];
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        to_return.push(document.getElementById(elements[i]));
    }
    return to_return;
}
```

This will accept an array of IDs as the parameter, and return the elements in an array. You might also want to look into the [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) method.

Comment: +1 even though there are other ways like querySelectorAll, sticking to  getElementById offers the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have upvoted @BenM's answer, but I'd like to suggest another option.

Your issue:

> I'm checking the background color of each cell

In this case, it would make more sense to attach the id to the table itself. Your selector becomes (assuming no nested table):

```
var cells = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("td");
```

or for recent browsers:

```
var cells = querySelectorAll("#myTable>tbody>tr>td");
```

For the record, here is another way if all your cells have a similar id "cellxxx":

```
var cells = querySelectorAll("td[id^='cell']");
```